# JSON: moving item's key/name into attribute and convert it to array with jq

Tags: json, jq

here is original json example:

```
{
  "item1": {
    "foo1": 1,
    "foo2": 2
},
  "item2": {
    "foo1": 11,
    "foo2": 22
  }
}
```

how can i convert it into json array with new attribute using jq:

```
[
  {
    "name": "item1",
    "foo1": 1,
    "foo2": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "item2",
    "foo1": 11,
    "foo2": 22
  }
]
```

also, it's very interesting, how opposite conversion can be done as well!

thanks in advance!

i have been trying different approaches using "keys" and "keys_unsorted", but never got it work ((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `keys` I would start with `to_entries`:

```
to_entries | map({name: .key} + .value)
```

<sup>([online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/98DMHXY56WS))</sup>

The reverse then is

```
map({key: .name, value: del(.name)}) | from_entries
```

<sup>([online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/uEIXGTe3dNy))</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
. as $arr | $arr
| keys                        # Get all keys (names) of the array
| map_values(
    . as $item | {
        item,                 # Preserve the original item
        attribute: $item | keys # Move name to "attribute" property
    }
)
```

Comment: sorry for dumb question: how do i run this in command line?